# A variety has two disjoint components iff its coordinate ring may be written as the product of 2 finitely generated k-algebras.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I realise there is a similar post, but I didn't find the answer there very helpful, and also I have an idea which could be a proof for one of the directions, but also could be nonsense

The question precisely is

> Show that a variety $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ has two disjoint components if and only if the coordinate ring $k[X]$ may be written as the product of two finitely generated $k$-algebras.

Now here's what I thought about one of the directions.

$X = V(I_1) \cup V(I_2)$ and $V(I_1)\cap V(I_2) = \phi $

Thus $I(X) = I(V(I_1)\cup V(I_2)) = I(V(I_1))\cap I(V(I_2)) = \sqrt{I_1}\cap \sqrt{I_2}$.

Also $I(V(I_1)\cap V(I_2))=\sqrt{I_1}\sqrt{I_2} = k[x_1,...,x_n]$

Now if we reduce $\sqrt{I_1}$ and $\sqrt{I_2}$ modulo $I(X)$ we still get radical ideals in $k[X]$ and thus they form two $k$-algebras whose product is $k[X]$.

I'm really not very sure how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: Did you mean $I(V(I_1)\cap V(I_2))=\sqrt{I_1+I_2}$?

Comment: @Mohan ahh yeah it seems what I wrote makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that $I_1$ and $I_2$ are coprime ideals. Once done, you can use Chinese Remainder Theorem and get a ring isomorphism: $k^{\oplus n}/(I_1 \cap I_2)\rightarrow k^{\oplus n}/I_1 \times k^{\oplus n}/I_2$.